# Bottle tree lighting

Tags: led

My wife has a bottle tree in the front yard. 50 bottles on it. I would like to put lights in all the bottles to be seen at night. I can wire a house up but can't find any individual small lights that are a/c current. Don't understand why (it seems to me) that all small lights are just D/C voltage. I don't want to put a transformer outside. Or do I have to?
Please help me make my wife happy.
Randy

Comment: Incandescent lamps run on either AC or DC just fine (though I'm not sure if it affects their lifetime). LEDs require DC because of how they work. In either case you'll probably need some kind of power supply (it won't be a plain transformer, those are outdated technology now).

Comment: Can you consider the idea of using the 3 V flashlight lamps and putting them in series? These work fine with AC and if you string up enough of them in series that might work more directly. There are tiny xenon bulbs for this. Isolation transformer may be important here.

Comment: You could always use neon bulbs.  Though they are not that bright, they do run on AC.  : https://www.intl-lighttech.com/specialty-light-sources/neon-lamps

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the issue isn't 12 VDC vs 12 VAC, but rather, wanting to run your bottle-tree lighting on **mains** voltage of 120 VAC or 230 VAC. **Mains voltage will kill you**.

As such, your nation will have an Electrical Code which describes proper *wiring methods* for wiring with mains voltage.  It's possible to get power there, but you have to follow the rules.  *If you don't, and someone gets hurt, expect to lose freedom, fortune or both.*

I know, right?  For EE's and electronic hobbyists, **wiring methods** are the last thing you ever think of.  It is the crux of electrician-type electrical work.  Playing fast-and-loose with wiring is fine for low-voltage lighting, which is why everyone's been frame-shifting you into it, as do I.  Outdoor "transformers"/power supplies are readily available, as LV lighting is widely used in outdoor garden, pool and path lighting **for exactly this reason**.

But if you really, really want to wire it 120/230V, grab that Electrical Code (or possibly your jurisdiction's appliance wiring standards, UL standards are generally accepted the world over) and build your fixture to code.  Hobbyists do it all the time, just usually they're building *chandeliers* that will be living indoors so they don't have to follow the "wet location" rules.

Honestly it seems like mains-voltage lighting would be too bright. (theorists: this is a *procurement* issue.)  By which I mean, you're trying to accent/highlight the bottles, not overwhelm them, and my hunch is you'll want a certain luminosity. IMO that'll be rather easy to buy in low-voltage, and it will be a struggle to source in mains voltage at sane cost, that is reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mini incandescent light bulbs (I found it on this [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EPQ7HSI)).
They use 1.5 volts, and you must consider about using a large number of light bulbs to fit with your home power source.

Comment: That would mean to put them in series, I wouldn't do that cause then you're probably constantly exchannging light bulbs.